# Popup value in Simulink Mask doesn't refresh

Tags: matlab, simulink, masking

I am currently masking a block in simulink.
The mask contains a popup list called dbclist with hardcoded type options (1, 2, 3, ..., 7).
The callback function of said popup list looks like this:

```
msk = Simulink.Mask.get(gcb);
dbcPopup = msk.getParameter('dbclist');
dbcPopup.Value
```

When changing the value of dbclist while using the mask the command window always responds with:

```
ans =

1


ans =

1


ans =

1
```

How can I get the actual value of dbclist? 
I am using MATLAB 2014b on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated here (http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/290286-popup-value-in-simulink-mask-doesn-t-refresh) I have found another way to get the actual value of my popuplist. I still don't know what is wrong with the first approach. If anyone figures out where the error is I would really appreciate telling me.